# How to filter IP from log file in another Rdd

Tags: java, apache-spark

I am fetching IP from the Access log file,tried using Pattern but not getting correct output.

```
public class IPcount {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    String IPADDRESS_PATTERN = "(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(IPADDRESS_PATTERN);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(t);

    JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext("local", "IPcount");
    @SuppressWarnings({ "unused", "serial" })
    JavaRDD<String> lines = sc.textFile("/home/bhaumik/Documents/access_log", 5)
            .flatMap(new FlatMapFunction<String, String>() {

                @Override
                public Iterable<String> call(String t) throws Exception {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    return null; //HERE WHAT SHOULD I DO SO THAT I CAN GET IP FILTER FROM THE LOG FILE.
                }
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: How it can be off topic when some one can give correct answer?? 
and i have explained it exactly..
that's why people gives me answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a Java method for extracting IPs from a `JavaRDD<String>`, assuming each line might contain zero, one, or more IPs:

```
public JavaRDD<String> getIPs(JavaRDD<String> rdd) {
    final String IPADDRESS_PATTERN = "(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)";
    final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(IPADDRESS_PATTERN);

    return rdd.flatMap(new FlatMapFunction<String, String>() {
        @Override
        public Iterable<String> call(String t) throws Exception {
            final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(t);
            final LinkedList<String> matches = new LinkedList<>();
            while (matcher.find()) {
                matches.add(matcher.group());
            }
            return matches;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help and efforts! @TzachZohar